# Select subset of elements from __m256 ?

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd, avx

I have a __m256, which is used to store 8 floats, the elements inside are like:

```
__m256 v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

Now I want to get another __m256 of values like:

```
__m256 dst = {0,1,2,4,5,6,x,x};
```

*x* here means I don't care.

I am not familiar with SIMD, could anybody help ? Or give me some hints ?

Thanks!

Comment: The details depend on which library you use to access the SIMD instructions. I guess `__m256` indicates some Intel stuff.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, I am using GCC on a Intel CPU which supports up to AVX2.

Comment: Maybe have a look at Intel's documentation, then? I'm pretty sure there must be tutorials also. I've never looked into this stuff.

Comment: What are you going to do with the result?  If you're copying between packed and padded vec3 formats, you could just use 128b loads/stores, and overlap the stores by one element.  If you can use AVX2, then it might be faster to load/shuffle/store overlapping by two elements, like you're proposing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use AVX2 intrinsic [_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524012). It helps you to shuffle elements inside 256-bit vector. See an example below:

```
__m256 a = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 };
__m256i k = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0);
__m256 b = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(a, k);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an instruction which will operate across 128 bit lanes. Unfortunately most AVX/AVX2 shuffle/permute instructions will only operate within the two 128 bit lanes of a 256 bit AVX vector, however there are a few which do not have this limitation. In this particular case the intrinsic you are looking for is [_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps&expand=4746,3875,3905,3905&techs=AVX,AVX2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(void)
{
    __m256 v0 = _mm256_setr_ps(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    __m256i vperm = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0);

    __m256 v1 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(v0, vperm);

    float f0[8], f1[8];

    _mm256_storeu_ps(f0, v0);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(f1, v1);

    printf("v0: %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", f0[0], f0[1], f0[2], f0[3], f0[4], f0[5], f0[6], f0[7]);
    printf("v1: %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", f1[0], f1[1], f1[2], f1[3], f1[4], f1[5], f1[6], f1[7]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mavx2 blackball.c 
$ ./a.out 
v0: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
v1: 0 1 2 4 5 6 0 0
```